# Where do Windows 10 screensaver images come from?

Tags: windows-10, screensaver

I have searched the C: drive exhaustively for any/all image files and I do find a few screensaver images, but not the ones that appear most often (or the ones I am interested in saving). I am guessing these missing screensaver images get downloaded over the internet and never get stored on the C: drive. Where do these Windows 2010 screensaver images come from? Are they stored on my machine anywhere?

Comment: Are you asking about the Lock Screen images?

Answer (score -3):

Screen saver files use the extension of .scr. In Windows File Explorer, use search and the search parameters of *.scr to search for all files of that file extension. In Windows 8.1 they are in C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64. I would think they are in the same place in Windows 10 but 10 is weird sometimes. I don't have a 10 machine available right now to check that.

This article here seems to indicate that 10 handles screensavers differently. 
https://www.howtogeek.com/225305/how-to-find-and-set-screen-savers-on-windows-10/
You apparently can use old .scr screen savers with Windows 10, but I don't think Windows 10 screen savers use that format. A guy at IT World had some fun making his own classic style screensavers using a hex editor.From what he said, if you put them in System32 they should work.
http://www.itworld.com/article/2889253/retro-fun-modify-classic-screensavers-to-use-with-windows-10-and-8-1.html

Comment: Why on earth am i getting down voted for answering in a technical and polite fashion? Is this community really so negative as to downvote people who answer in contradiction to their own answers? Can we please bring some civility back?